# Android HTTP Post is slow

Tags: android, performance, http-post

I know this has been asked a few times here but I've used every method on here and read everything I can think to read but I'm still having issues. I've even used a couple libraries including this one (https://github.com/koush/ion) to no avail.

I'm using a godaddy shared hosting plan. Sometimes it's very quick to execute my commands and other times it takes quite some time. Last try took 9 seconds but then I have others which are less than a second.

The biggest issue however is uploading an image just doesn't work. I have the same app doing the same thing in iOS and it uploads to the godaddy server and my exact same code works on mamp in Android but stops once it's taken live which rules out a code issue in my books.

iOS is always fast and consistent using the same server, however, Android varies from fast to a crawl, what's up?

My current method looks like this

```
     public String postData(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {
        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            httppost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if(responseEntity!=null) {
                return EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I've experienced same odd slow rates while using Ion/Koush. Would like to know what's the matter.